# SyntaxError: Unexpected token then used @storybook/addon-storyshots

Tags: javascript, jestjs, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

i used addon-storyshots. But then i run test with jest i have one error.
I read many resources how win this problem, but all i found dont help me. 
Example [storybook issues](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7246)

Please help me.

[image: error message]

My config files:

**storybook version**

```
@storybook/react: "^5.3.13",
@storybook/addon-knobs: "^5.3.13",
@storybook/addon-info: "^5.3.13",
@storybook/addon-storyshots: "^5.3.13",
```

**storyshots.test.js**

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

initStoryshots();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    config.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules(?!\/@storybook\/addon-info)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                { loader: 'css-loader' },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins() {
                            return [require('precss'), require('autoprefixer')];
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        data: `@import "~@someRepo/theme-ctms/styles/publicVariables.scss";`,
                        includePaths: [__dirname, '/src']
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
    );
    return config;
};
```

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-info', '@storybook/addon-knobs/register']
};
```

**test.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/(.*)':
            'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/$1'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules/(?!react-syntax-highlighter|@storybook)'
    ]
};
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Using main,js and preview.js. Same versions of the modules: 5.3.13. Using latest Creat React App as base

Comment: I abandoned addon-info and ended up using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-docs 

It seems to be the new "hot" replacement for addon info